# Custom Apache 2.2 directory pages

Tags: apache-2.2

Like the title says, I want to take the ugly default HTML 3.2 directory page that come with Apache, and replace it with a modern, better looking page.

Anyone know how? Is it even possible? Is the page generated somewhere deep inside the source code? Tell me stuff like that, please.

P.S. I use the built in Apache server on Mac OS X 10.6.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean the file listing you see of a webserver directory when there is no index.html present and +Indexes is on -- All you need to do is add a html file with the style/fanciness you want and point apache at it with the

`HeaderName /header.html`

directive.  It'll be included at the top of every auto-generated index.

The directory lists are indeed created in the guts of apache, by mod_autoindex, which is where I found this directive: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html

Comment: What module is HeaderName included in?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html#headername

Comment: Thanks. I was able to do pretty much what I wanted to do. Not exactly, but close. :)